# How to iterate over object list in reverse order in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp, grails-domain-class

From a list of GORM database objects that are ordered desc in my user domain model I want to order them asc (i.e., in reverse order in the view). For example to get the latest books of a user from the database, but insert them in the Dom in reverse order where the latest book comes last.

How do I perform a reverse each in my GSP?

Controller:

```
def books = user.books
```

GSP:

```
<g:each in="${books}" var="book">${book}</g:each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<g:each in="${books.reverse()}" var="book">${book}</g:each>`

EDIT

Got carried away :). I would rather suggest:

`def books = user.books?.reverse()` in controller.

(Separation of concern, view should not have logic of manipulating `model`)

**UPDATE:**

In case `books` are not ordered in `User`, explicit sorting is required.

`def newestBooks = user.books?.asList().sort{it.publishDate}`

to reverse sort use

`def newestBooks = user.books?.asList().sort{-it.publishDate}`

Comment: I disagree, the model implies no order. Tables are not ordered. In my opinion, the order in which objects display is part of the logic of the view.

Comment: If I have `def newestBooks = user.books?.reverse()` set to model?

Comment: This is not working because there is no order in the domain class.

Comment: The question says the objects are ordered desc in `user` domain. If that is not the case then it has to be sorted in the controller as shown in the update above in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use default sort for relation collection as described [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder). So if you define like this:

```
class User {
    …
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    static mapping = {
        books sort: 'publishDate', order: 'asc'
    }
}
```

The collection will be sorted on database level